# Association in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and am struggling a little to understand the correct usage of associations and so am having an issue getting my code to work. I have reviewed rubyonrails.org but still am unsure.

I have 3 tables (mySQL), one that will contain products, one for the retailers that sell those products and one that links a product to a retailer and has a price. A retailer can stock many products and a product can be sold by many retailers. For this reason I went for a 'has many and belongs to many' approach.

My API will return json containing details about the product + the retailer who is selling it + the price that the retailer is selling it at.

When i run my code I am getting the following error:
"Association named 'products' was not found on ProductPrice; perhaps you misspelled it?"

**My Models:**

```
    class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

    class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_and_belongs_to_many :productprices
    end

    class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_and_belongs_to_many :productprices
    end
```

**Controller:**

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ProductDetailsController < ApplicationController          
            def show
                @prod = ProductPrice.joins(:products, :retailers)
                render json: @prod
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

**Migration files:**

```
class CreateRetailers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :retailers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
      t.string :aff_id
      t.string :img_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :brand
        t.string :category
        t.string :sub_cat
        t.string :nut_cal
        t.string :nut_pro
        t.string :nut_fat
        t.string :nut_sat_fat
        t.string :nut_carb
        t.string :nut_sugar
        t.string :nut_salt
        t.text :ingredients
        t.string :flavours
        t.text :description
        t.string :img_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProductPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :product_prices do |t|
        t.belongs_to :product, index: true 
        t.belongs_to :retailer, index: true
        t.string :price
        t.string :aff_link

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

A few questions:

- Given the scenario I am trying to achieve, have I used the correct
  association?
- What changes do I need to make to solve the error?

  Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a join table in the db to have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "The Rails 4 Way", the authors mention the HABTM association but are quick to also say that many Rails developers feel it is practically obsolete.  I would change those to simple `has_many` associations and add `belongs_to` in your `ProductPrices` model.

Also, by convention, models should be singular.  So, I would change:

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
```

to:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: I can't agree more that HABTM is not useful, especially in the long run.

Comment: Hi Steve, I made the changes you suggested above however it is returning only the results from the table and not all details that matched. if I do .select("*") this works but I understand that this is bad practice - can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Make sure your code follows what Ilan posted below.  If it is still not working, it might be best to post a new question with your current code and new issue.  Otherwise, this thread will become pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :product_retailers, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
     has_many :retailers, through: :project_retailers   
   end

   class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :product_retailers, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :retailer
      has_many :products, through: :product_retailers     
    end

   class ProductRetailer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :product
     belongs_to :retailer
     validates_presence_of :price, :product, :retailer
     validates_numeracality_of :price, greater_than: 0
   end
```

migration

```
create_table :product_retailers do |t|
  t.float :price, null: false
  t.references :product, null: false
  t.references :retailer, null: false
end
```